# Vespa query filter - how to check whether a specific int is in a document's int array<int> field

Tags: arrays, filtering, yql, vespa

What's the proper way to check whether an integer is inside an array field when filtering in a Vespa query?

Given the following field in a document:

```
field location_ids type array<int> {
    indexing: summary | attribute
}
```

I want to filter documents that contain a specific integer ID:

```
{'yql': 'SELECT * FROM doc WHERE userQuery() AND <int X in location_ids>',
'query': 'some query text'
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this with an int array, as the docs and project examples dealt mainly with string arrays.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single value X

```
{'yql': 'SELECT * FROM doc WHERE userQuery() AND location_ids=X',
'query': 'some query text'
}
```

Will match if X is in the array.

Comment: The solution is not working for me. The type of my `organization` field is `array<string>`; however, `organization contains 'Starbucks'` or `organization = 'Starbucks'` under the WHERE is not working for me.. I mean it returns with `{'totalCount': 0}`.

Comment: This depends on the match settings of your string fields. Also, the syntax for string is `contains`, not `=`, which is reserved for numeric fields.

Comment: Hi, I'm still learning about Vespa. Could you explain more about "how the matching works for the text fields"? Or, any pointer to reading material would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Girishkumar, this is a good start on text matching and how Vespa allows different matching modes https://docs.vespa.ai/en/text-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

Searching numeric values (equals, range etc.) is documented at https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/query-language-reference.html#numeric

Comment: Great thanks Jon, I'll take a look again. I didn't realise it meant integers could be evaluated directly against arrays.